# sapui5 coordinate plotting

Tags: sapui5

A question regarding below process. I have a table maintained in blue box. Sample table maintenance and expected output.

[image: sample table maintenance and expected output]

How could I render the coordinates to a clickable table/grid like what is shown in red box. Which SAPUI5 control able to achieve this objective? The X will be the lot id which will be maintained in the table and it shall have an event triggered to show the detail information when user click on the cell. Some lot will have single cell and some will need to merge cell(Note: if the coordinate is not maintained, it shall leaves blank to that cell and is non-clickable).

Does this requirment able to achive using sapui5 for fiori app?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, but not all of them offer the complete set of functionality that you describe.

The first way that comes into mind is to use a [sap.m.Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.m.Table) with the "mergeDuplicates" properties set on the columns. Example (working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zw25cLpo/1/)):

```xml
<Table>
    <columns>
    <Column mergeDuplicates="true">
        <header><Label text="1" /></header>
    </Column>
    <Column mergeDuplicates="true">
        <header><Label text="2" /></header>
    </Column>
    <Column mergeDuplicates="true">
        <header><Label text="3" /></header>
    </Column>
  </columns>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <Button text="A"/>
    <Button text="B"/>
    <Button text="X"/>
  </ColumnListItem>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <Button text="A"/>
    <Button text="C"/>
    <Button text="C"/>
  </ColumnListItem>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <Button text="A"/>
    <Button text="C"/>
    <Button text="C"/>
  </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

The main downside of this is that you cannot merge cells across columns (i.e. in this example, you would get cell "C" twice: once for the second column and once for the third).

Another version is to use the [sap.ui.layout.Grid](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.layout.Grid). This has mostly the same limitation (that you can only merge "cells" in a single direction) and also has the added limitation that:

> The Grid control is a layout which positions its child controls in a 12 column flow layout.

Lastly, you could use a [sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout) (which is deprecated btw, but no "full" replacement was provided). This actually can be used to model your problem completely. Example (working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0byjmgbh/1/)):

```xml
<layout:MatrixLayout class="matrix">
    <layout:rows>
    <layout:MatrixLayoutRow height="4em">
        <layout:MatrixLayoutCell padding="None" rowSpan="3">
            <Button text="A" width="100%"/>
        </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
      <layout:MatrixLayoutCell padding="None">
            <Button text="B" width="100%"/>
        </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
      <layout:MatrixLayoutCell padding="None">
            <Button text="X" width="100%"/>
        </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
    </layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
    <layout:MatrixLayoutRow height="4em">
        <layout:MatrixLayoutCell padding="None" colSpan="2" rowSpan="2" >
            <Button text="C" width="100%"/>
        </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
    </layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
    <layout:MatrixLayoutRow height="4em">
    </layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
  </layout:rows>
</layout:MatrixLayout>
```

But as you see, it is slightly more complicated and may need some CSS fiddling.

Comment: I believe table control will not able to achieve my objective. sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout do model the design but it is now deprecated. Will that be an issue for future maintenance? One more question on my coordinate maintenance table? What's the format to store in order for me able to loop as internal table and able to retrieve and populate it dynamically. As it might have unknown N columns and N rows to be populated.